# How to detect when AVPlayer video ends playing?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, avplayer

I'am using AVPlayer for playing local video file (mp4) in Swift.
Does anyone know how to detect when video finish with playing?
Thanks

Comment: ObjC example but you can go with the same way: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6837002/no-avplayer-delegate-how-to-track-when-song-finished-playing-objective-c-iphon

Answer (score 138):

To get the `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification` your object needs to be an  `AVPlayerItem`.

To do so, just use the **`.currentItem`** property on your `AVPlayer`

Now you will get a notification once the video ends!

See my example:

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)       

NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "playerDidFinishPlaying:",
        name: AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
}
```

**Swift 3**

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)       

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), 
       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: videoPlayer.currentItem)
    
func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    print("Video Finished")
}
```

Don't forget to remove the Observer in your `deinit`

**Swift 4, 5**

```
NotificationCenter.default
    .addObserver(self,
    selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying),
    name: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
    object: videoPlayer.currentItem
)
```

Comment: do you know what the difference between using this method and using the AVPlayer method `addPeriodicTimeObserver(TimeInterval:)` ?

Comment: addPeriodicTimeObeserver is used when you want to be notified when the time interval is up. for example, if you want to be notified every 0.5 second, you'd create a CMTime of 0.5 seconds and the callback would be invoked every 0.5 seconds.

Comment: does this addObserver induce memory leak when used multiple times?

Comment: how to remove it please

Comment: From https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/releasenotes/Foundation/RN-FoundationOlderNotes/index.html#10_11NotificationCenter In OS X 10.11 and iOS 9.0 NSNotificationCenter and NSDistributedNotificationCenter will no longer send notifications to registered observers that may be deallocated.

Comment: Passing the currentItem for the `object` Parameter was the important part - check that if you have problems.

Comment: wrong on two counts (1) you actually don't have to pass anything as an object (2) for years now, no need to deinit notifications

Comment: Can I use the function didFinishPlaying to reset the seekTime to zero? If so, how do I do that?

Comment: I had added `NotificationCenter.default.addObserver...` and declared @objc in my Swift class but the @objc is never called. I am using Xcode 13

Answer (score 41):

**Swift 3.0**

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)

NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
        print("Video Finished")
    }
```

Comment: But it says [myClass playerDidFinishPlaying:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: `#selector(playerDidFinishPlaying)`

Comment: does this addObserver induce memory leak when used multiple times?

Comment: Should I remove the observer? How do I do that?

Answer (score 17):

Swift 4.2 Version:

```
var player: AVPlayer!
  //
  //
// Configure Player
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let filepath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "selectedFileName", ofType: "mp4")
    if let filepath = filepath {
        let fileURL = URL.init(fileURLWithPath: filepath)
        player = AVPlayer(url: fileURL)
        let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
        // Register for notification
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self,
                                               selector: #selector(playerItemDidReachEnd),
                                                         name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
                                                         object: nil) // Add observer

        playerLayer.frame = self.view.bounds
        self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        player.play()
    }
}
// Notification Handling
@objc func playerItemDidReachEnd(notification: NSNotification) {
    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    player.play()
}
// Remove Observer
deinit {
    NotificationCenter.default.removeObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: 2019-4-20, XCode 10.2.1, Swift 5, Work for me, Thanks

Answer (score 10):

If you fancy using Combine:

```
private var cancelBag: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
.sink { _ in
    player.seek(to: CMTime.zero)
    player.play()
}
.store(in: &cancelBag)
```

Answer (score 9):

**SWIFT 5 Update**

The observer method with @objc function is not native. It is better to use event publisher in swift 5. Very simple.

Declare the following in the struct:

```
var pub = NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
```

Then on any view, add

```
.onReceive(pub) { (output) in
    print("Video Finished")
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**For SWIFT 3.0**
This is working fine

```
class PlayVideoViewController: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(PlayVideoViewController.finishVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTimeNotification, object: nil)
    }

    func finishVideo()
    {
        print("Video Finished")
    }
}
```

Comment: nil is the magic word, or else you have to add/remove to every item you add

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 4.0**

This one works for me. Thanks to @Channel

```
    private func playVideo(fileURL: String) {

            // Create RUL object
            let url = URL(string: fileURL)

            // Create Player Item object
            let playerItem: AVPlayerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
            // Assign Item to Player
            let player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)

            // Prepare AVPlayerViewController
            let videoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
            // Assign Video to AVPlayerViewController
            videoPlayer.player = player

            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(myViewController.finishVideo), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

            // Present the AVPlayerViewController
            present(videoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
                    // Play the Video
                    player.play()
            })

    }

    @objc func finishVideo()
    {
            print("Video Finished")
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

## 2023

It's really this simple

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
    // Note, somewhat bizarrely, it's perfectly OK to add
    // the end time notification once for a view controller,
    // and even before you create the player, etc. See notes.

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
        self,
        selector: #selector(fileComplete),
        name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime,
        object: nil
    )

    ...
```

(It's fine for the `object` (last argument of the call) to be nil.)

and then

```
@objc func fileComplete() {
    print("one video has reached -0 time")
}
```

## You just put this in viewDidLoad.

Here's why ...

## IF YOU PLAY MORE THAN ONE VIDEO:

If you run the above code more than once, you will get more than one notification each time a video ends. ie "fileComplete" will be called more than once.

Typically your code will look something like ..

- user taps to play video X
- your code to play a specific video
- user taps to change to video Y
- your code to play a specific video

Somewhat annoyingly, you have to arrange to call the code in question, `.addObserver`, ***only one time for your overall system***.

And, yes, it's totally OK to `.addObserver` even if you have not yet brought up your AVPlayer.

Indeed the best place to do it is just viewDidLoad - ensuring it only runs once.

## If using code as in the example you do NOT need to remove the observer

For years now in iOS you don't need to remove the observer, when, the screen goes away. This is fully documented at Apple.

To be clear, if you use the block form of `addObserver` then you must still remove the observer when done. Use the selector form of addObserver (as in the code example here) and you don't need to explicitly remove the observer when done.

Comment: To be clear, if you use the block form of `addObserver` then you must still remove the observer when done. It's only the selector form of `addObserver` where you don't need to explicitly remove the observer when done.

Answer (score 4):

Swift 3.0

```
let videoPlayer = AVPlayer(URL: url)
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
    //Called when player finished playing
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**For SWIFT 3.0**

Here 'fullUrl' is the URL of the video and make sure that there would be no space in the URL, You should replace 'Space' with '%20' so that URL will work file.

```
  let videoURL = NSURL(string: fullUrl)
  let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL! as URL)

  playerViewController.delegate = self
  playerViewController.player = player
  self.present(playerViewController, animated: false) {

    self.playerViewController.player!.play()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(yourViewControllerName.playerDidFinishPlaying), name: Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: self.player?.currentItem)
  }
```

Add this below given method in your view controller.

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(){    
print("Video Finished playing in style")
}
```

Comment: does this addObserver induce memory leak when used multiple times?

Answer (score 3):

I know there are a lot of accepted answers here...

But, another route might be to add a boundary time observer to your AVPlayer.  You would have to have the duration of the video, which you can get from your `player.currentItem`, and then add it as your desired time boundary.

```
fileprivate var videoEndObserver: Any?

func addVideoEndObserver() {
    guard let player = YOUR_VIDEO_PLAYER else { return }

    // This is just in case you are loading a video from a URL.
    guard let duration = player.currentItem?.duration, duration.value != 0 else {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.5, execute: { [weak self] in
            self?.addVideoEndObserver()
        })

        return
    }

    let endTime = NSValue(time: duration - CMTimeMakeWithSeconds(0.1, duration.timescale))
    videoEndObserver = player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [endTime], queue: .main, using: {
        self.removeVideoEndObserver()

        // DO YOUR STUFF HERE...
    })
}

func removeVideoEndObserver() {
    guard let observer = videoEndObserver else { return }

    videoPlayer.player?.removeTimeObserver(observer)
    videoEndObserver = nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In Swift 3 and RxSwift 3.5 all you have to do is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.rx.notification(Notification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime)
        .asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] notification in

            //Your action

        }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil, queue: .main) { noti in
        guard let item = noti.object as? AVPlayerItem else{
            return
        }
        //DidPlayToEndTime
    }
```

Comment: This this a perfect and simple answer and it can be used in swiftui easily.

Answer (score 2):

```
func shareEditedVedio() -> AVPlayer {
    let editedVedioPlayer = AVPlayer(url: self.vedioData.vedioURLWithAddedSounds!)
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector:#selector(self.playerDidFinishPlaying(note:)),name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: editedVedioPlayer.currentItem)
    return editedVedioPlayer
}


@objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
    //Called when player finished playing
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `Combine`, and also making sure the notification comes from the AVPlayerItem you are interested in and not just any. I am playing multiple items at once, so this would work in that scenario as well.

```
private var subscriptions: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: .AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: player.currentItem)
    .receive(on: RunLoop.main)
    .sink { [weak self] notification in
        guard let item = notification.object as? AVPlayerItem else { return }
        if item == self?.player.currentItem {
         //.... Here you know it was the item you are interested in that played to end and not just any
        }
    }
    .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with the Notification never getting called, setting the notification inside the presentation of the AVPlayerViewController solved it for me:

```
func presentVideo(url:URL) {
        let player = AVPlayer(url: url)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                playerViewController.player!.play()
                //NOTE: The notification must be created here for it to work as expected
                NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.videoDidEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Another solution:

```
player.observe(\AVPlayer.actionAtItemEnd) { player, _ in
    print("video did end")
}
```

Comment: would have been nice if this works. but no, it doesnt