# AVQueuePlayer Current Item Changed

Tags: swift, avfoundation, avplayer, avplayeritem, avqueueplayer

I am using QueuePlayer to play a list of songs and the songs are playing. My issue is that I am trying to track whenever the current item changes. 
I try adding an observer to the QueuePlayer, but this isn't working. The observing func isn't getting called. Any help would be appreciated

**Observer**

```
 queuePlayer.currentItem?.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", options: [.new, .old], context: nil)
    }
```

**Listening for observer** // Not getting called when item changes

```
override func observeValue(forKeyPath keyPath: String?, of object: Any?, change: [NSKeyValueChangeKey : Any]?, context: UnsafeMutableRawPointer?) {
    if keyPath == "currentItem" {
        if let oldItem = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.oldKey] as? AVPlayerItem {
            print("Old item : \(oldItem)")
        }

        if let newItem = change?[NSKeyValueChangeKey.newKey] as? AVPlayerItem {
            print("New item : \(newItem)")
        }    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is observing the `currentItem` property of `queuePlayer.currentItem`.

To observe the `currentItem` property of `queuePlayer`, it should be

```
queuePlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", …
```

or better yet, for compile time checking…

```
queuePlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: #keyPath(AVQueuePlayer.currentItem), …
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I tried your answer "queuePlayer.addObserver(self, forKeyPath: "currentItem", … This didn't work, observer function still not getting called.

Answer (score -1):

If you need to know when an item finished playing, you can go something like.

> Inside your `viewdidload()`,  add observer

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(itemDidPlayToEnd), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: nil)

@objc func itemDidPlayToEnd() {

    //your item played to end
  }
```

I Just verified that its working fine

[This may also be helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34644343/7698092)