# Automatically dismiss AVPlayer when video completes from ALL SCREENS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, ipad

When my video completes, I want it to pull down the AVPlayer and return to the Main View Controller.

I also want to pull the video down from my external screen/display when that's connected.

How do I do this?

I've tried a few different answers on here and none of them have worked so far.

NOTE: Four is the name of my video

```
@IBAction func fourVideoPlayButton(_ sender: Any) {

    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Four", ofType: "mp4") {

        let fourVideo = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        let fourVideoPlayer = AVPlayerViewController()
        fourVideoPlayer.player = fourVideo

        present(fourVideoPlayer, animated: true, completion: {
            fourVideo.play()
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect when AVPlayer video ends playing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29386531/how-to-detect-when-avplayer-video-ends-playing)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add observer to detect when player is finished playing by

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: Selector(("playerDidFinishPlaying:")), 
       name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: fourVideoPlayer.player.currentItem)

func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
    fourVideoPlayer.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Hope this help!

Comment: How can I dismiss this also from my external display/screen?

Comment: are you saying dismiss from another viewController?

Comment: So I have my app connected to an external display over Apple TV. When the video completes it removes the AVPlayer+Controller from the user device (iPad) but it just leaves the end frame on the TV.

Comment: Oh, so you can try following
fourVideoPlayer.view.removeFromSuperView()
self.presentedviewController?.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

Comment: It's giving me the error Value of type 'UIView?' has no member 'removeFromSuperView'

Comment: fixed that UIView problem but it still displays on my external screen.

Comment: were you able to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

In **Swift 4.2**,

```
let fourPlayerController = AVPlayerViewController()

    @IBAction func fourVideoPlayButton(_ sender: Any) {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Four", ofType:"mp4") else {
            return
        }
        let fourVideoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
        fourPlayerController.player = fourVideoPlayer
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(playerDidFinishPlaying), name: NSNotification.Name.AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime, object: fourPlayerController.player?.currentItem)

        present(fourPlayerController, animated: true) {
            fourVideoPlayer.play()
        }
    }

    @objc func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification) {
        fourPlayerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
        fourPlayerController.dismiss(true, completion: nil)
        fourPlayerController.view.removeFromSuperview()
        self.presentedViewController?. dismiss(true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks @Bappaditya it worked. I'm using an external display also, Do you know why it won't dismiss off my external display also? It just displays the end frame of the video when complete. I want it to return to my main external view.

Comment: If you can share some code snippet, that will help me to understand the flow better

Comment: var secondWindow: UIWindow!
    var secondScreenView: UIView!
    
    @objc func setupScreen(){
        if UIScreen.screens.count > 1{
            let secondScreen = UIScreen.screens[1]
            secondWindow = UIWindow(frame: secondScreen.bounds)
            let viewController = UIViewController()
            secondWindow!.rootViewController = viewController
            secondWindow!.screen = secondScreen
            secondScreenView = UIView(frame: secondWindow!.frame)
            secondWindow!.addSubview(secondScreenView)
            secondWindow!.isHidden = false

Comment: Sorry for the mess above. You can view here if it's easier. https://codeshare.io/2EwxqK

Comment: Were you able to figure it out @Bappaditya?

Comment: @ Bappaditya still same issue. Could it be I don't have an AVPlayerItem. Also Xcode made me change fourPlayerController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil) TO fourPlayerController.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)