# I am loading videos in AVPlayer in collection view but it repeats some cells data

Tags: swift

I am loading videos in AVPlayer in collection view. Some cells repeat data. How to resolve this issue?

```
 func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell:homecollCell = self.collectionview.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "homecollCell", for: indexPath) as! homecollCell
    //cell.player?.pause()

    let obj = self.friends_array[indexPath.row] as! Home

    cell.img.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:self.appDelegate.imgbaseUrl!+obj.thum), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: ""))

    let url = URL.init(string: self.appDelegate.imgbaseUrl!+obj.video_url)

    let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds
    cell.playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: url!)
    //cell.player!.replaceCurrentItem(with: cell.playerItem)
    cell.player = AVPlayer(playerItem: cell.playerItem!)
    cell.playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: cell.player!)
    cell.playerLayer!.frame = CGRect(x:0,y:0,width:screenSize.width,height: screenSize.height)
    cell.playerLayer!.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill
    cell.playerView.layer.addSublayer(cell.playerLayer!)

    cell.player?.play()
```

Comment: Cells are reused, so `cell.playerView.layer.addSublayer(cell.playerLayer!)` might strongly cause an issue.

Comment: Any Solution of this

Comment: You can remove player whenever cell disappears, and prepare/setup player for which cell will be appear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cells are reusable so you have to remove or discard the changes what you have done on other cells using `prepareForReuse()`. Simply like this. Call this inside `cell`.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
     super.prepareForReuse()
     self.label.text = nil
}
```

Comment: Thanks Good Answer

Comment: Another question from you how I check when player stop and when avplayer

Comment: @RaoMudassarKhalil this one may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48510275/8368982

Comment: its the solution of Video end and start I want to say actually how to get when video start playing and when start buffering