# Returning to a previous view controller

Tags: swift, storyboard, uistoryboard, viewcontroller, xcode11.4

I have a view controller which I made through coding rather than storyboard to display a video. 
once the video has finished playing I cannot get the view controller to return to the previous one. I have a button which takes the user to the video but when the video finish it doesn't go back to the previous view controller.

```
import AVKit
import AVFoundation
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)

        let player = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.path(forResource: "tour", ofType: "mov")!))


   let vc = AVPlayerViewController()
      vc.player = player
     present(vc, animated: true)
    }


}
```

this is my code for my video. I have done everything else to build the app on my storyboard

Comment: please show example code

Comment: I have included it. thank you

Comment: You don't need to call a new viewcontroller to call AVPlayerViewController(), try to call it on the previous viewcontroller then when it dismiss will stay at the controller that you wanted

Answer (score 0):

To go back to the previous VC after the video finishes, you need to -

1. add an observer which could detect when the video stops playing and then -
2. dismiss the `AVPlayerViewController`

To accomplish task 1 - this answer by Channel helps set up the observer -https://stackoverflow.com/a/40056529/13451699

To do task 2 - just dismiss the `AVPlayerViewController` from inside the `playerDidFinishPlaying` function, like so :

```
func playerDidFinishPlaying(note: NSNotification){
  // Video finished playing
  self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: I am new to coding. could you please explain to me how I will do task 2, how will I add the observer to my swift code. also to dismiss AVPlayerViewController should I just delete that section. thank you

Comment: I've edited the answer to illustrate how you could accomplish task 2

Comment: Happy to help.. If the answer helped, please accept it :)