# Why is AVPlayer Boundary Time Observer not working?

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avkit

I am trying to observe a time in the timeline of my AVPlayer.

I tried this on the main queue; which did not work. I then switched to a background queue, as advised from [this stack overflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15771549/avplayer-boundary-time-observer-fails-to-fire-occasionally); which did not with either. Looking for a working solution or an explanation as to why this isn't working.

```
//add boundary time notification to global queue
avLayer.player!.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [NSValue(time: avLayer.player!.currentItem!.duration)], queue: DispatchQueue.main){

                        self.avLayer.player!.pause()
                    }
```

```
//add boundary time notification to background queue                
avLayer.player!.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [NSValue(time: avLayer.player!.currentItem!.duration)], queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInteractive)){

                        self.avLayer.player!.pause()
                    }
```

**Update:** After retaining a strong reference to the return value of the observer, I set a breakpoint in the callback. It is still not working.

```
 //add boundary time notification
                    boundaryTimeObserver = avLayer.player!.addBoundaryTimeObserver(forTimes: [NSValue(time: avLayer.player!.currentItem!.duration)], queue: DispatchQueue.main){

                        self.avLayer.player!.pause()
                    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There may be two problems:

1. As the documentation for `addBoundaryTimeObserver` states:

   > You must maintain a strong reference to the returned value as long as you want the time observer to be invoked by the player

   As your initial code does not keep a reference to the returned internal opaque time observer, the observer probably is released immediately and thus is never called.
2. Make sure the time you register for observing actually has the correct value:

   - *playerItem.duration* may be indefinite (see documentation of this property)
   - even the duration of the playerItem's `asset` may be unknown, or an in-precise estimation, depending on the type of the asset and loading state (again, see documentation of `AVAsset.duration` on this).

   As a consequence, the time you register for observing may never be reached (note that the time can easily be checked by inserting a `CMTimeShow(duration)`)

**Approaches to resolve this:**

- if you just want to stop the player when the playerItem's end is reached, setting `player.actionAtItemEnd` to `pause` may be sufficient
- if you need to execute some custom logic when the item's end is reached, register an observer for `AVPlayerItemDidPlayToEndTime` notifications with the playerItem as object. This mechanism is independent from possibly in-precise durations and so hopefully more reliable

Comment: I have retained the reference but the observer is still not being called. Please see the update.

Answer (score 4):

## 2019 simple example ..

```
var player = AVPlayer()
var token: Any?

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    let u = "https... "
    
    let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(url: URL(string: u)!)
    player = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem)
    player.play()

    token = player.addBoundaryTimeObserver(
       forTimes: [0.5 as NSValue],
       queue: DispatchQueue.main) { [weak self] in
         self?.spinner.stopAnimating()
         print("The audio is in fact beginning about now...")
    }
}
```

Works perfectly.

## Important .. it won't find "0"

Use a small value to find the "beginning" as a quick solution.

Comment: definitely appreciate the added note about not finding 0